# Office 2010 Privacy Options Automation

Tags: privacy, microsoft-office-2010, options

How can I remotely disable all of the Privacy Options within the Microsoft Office Trust Center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, phew. Had to do some research to make this one happen. I'm writing this assuming that you're familiar with using group policy, and are comfortable with it.

First, you're going to need this download:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=64b837b6-0aa0-4c07-bc34-bec3990a7956 -- This is the "Office 2010 Administrative Template files (ADM, ADMX/ADML) and Office Customization Tool".

You're also going to need this PDF file:
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CBsQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F0%2F3%2F1%2F0310F9DD-9E4F-47D1-80FF-C3AD0142E2DF%2FORKGroupPolicy.pdf&ei=bKU4TfmUIoeosAOw07TNAw&usg=AFQjCNGpcooIkaiAkqJbkN2oh4rr0-Mkvw -- This is an IT document for Group Policy and Office 2010.

Last, but not least, this is the group policy overview for Office 2010:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc179176.aspx -- This'll help you get the ADM files installed, and all that jazz.

Okay, now you have the tools. The next thing is using them. Inside the PDF at page 143, they start to talk about modifying the privacy options of Office 2010 installations using Group Policy.

If you use these tools, and you follow the instructions in the documentation, and you ask if you're stuck, this should be everything you need to do what you want.

Comment: This looks very promising John, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hey, no problem! Let me know if you get snagged, and I'll help ya out the best I can!